# get string in between with python

Tags: python, regex, tabs

Looking for a way to get items in between tabs

```
\t_e\t1\t_
```

I need to get the 1 but in other cases it will be a longer string.

```
re.search("\t_e\t(.*)\t_", string).group(1)
```

9 times out of 10 that line returns the string/value i want but not always, just to be clear after the underscore it could be any anything from a letter to a white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the regex lazy by adding a `?` character after `*`, like so:

```
re.search("\t_e\t(.*?)\t_", string).group(1)
                    ^
```

This makes the `.*` match as little as possible until the next `\t` (and thus prevents `.` to eat up a `\t`).

Comment: I know i'm not allowed to say thanks but i just got to. THANKS. I did think to put the question mart after the underscore but not in the actual match section.

Comment: @user1620852 Saying only 'thanks' is discouraged, but not strictly prohibited :) Glad it helped you! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.findall(r"(?s)(?<=\t)(.*?)(?=\t)", "\t_e\t1\t_")
```

output:

```
['_e', '1']
```

Basically, it is using positive lookahead and lookbehind assertion.  Also, the `(?s)` sets the "dotall" flag, allowing it to match whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find longest matches that doesn't include `\t`

```
>>> re.findall(r'([^\t]+)', '\t_e\t1\t_')
['_e', '1', '_']
```